# Should I simply partition a drive and install Ubuntu straight from my USB?

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

So I installed Ubuntu Desktop on an 8GB USB Stick. I tested it in the boot manager and everything seems to be running smoothly. For the sake of learning linux and practicing commands (I am an amateur with a VERY mild background in programming, and no linux experience) etc, should I just use Ubuntu on the USB drive until I feel more comfortable to install it onto a partitioned drive? Or should I just install it right away? Are the only restrictions to using it on a USB limited to the amount of space the USB has?

I guess it boils down to a preference thing but I eventually plan on switching over to linux completely on my laptop. 
Currently, I have a MacBook Air and 20GB of free space left on my HDD. What do you think? **One reason I am hesitant is because I read on that 25GB of space is recommended on a partitioned drive, I barely have 20. Will this be an issue/something to worry about?**

Thanks.

Comment: If you are testing Ubuntu running it from USB you should do a Full install to USB, not a Persistent or Live install. A full install boots faster is more secure and makes better use of space. A Full install takes about 5GB, an 8GB drive does not leave much space for programs, etc. 25GB usually keeps me happy for awhile.

Comment: Q: "One reason I am hesitant is because I read on that 25GB of space is recommended on a partitioned drive, I barely have 20. Will this be an issue/something to worry about?" - A: "20 GB should be enough for Ubuntu, but you must have some free space left in your MacOS too, for it to work."

Comment: Perhaps consider running off an external USB SSD or HDD. My wife runs Ubuntu from a 2TB USB drive. She takes it with her when she travels and plugs it into whatever is available. At home she plugs it into a mini i7 with Ubuntu installed on a SSD. She uses home from the USB drive. and only uses 20GB on the internal drive for /, (OS,programs and such), since home is external. She has close to 1.5TB of stuff in her home folder. She usually does not complain about speed.

Answer (score 0):

20 GB is enough to install but will not be enough to do much with it. If you add very many programs or store much data to you home directory it will fill up very fast.  Really think you need more drive space.